# Eclipse Scout callback for entering value in fields

Tags: infinite-loop, eclipse-scout

I would like to know if there is a function that fires up when user set value in field but not if program set value in field.

so function :

```
user click on field 'myField and change value -> method fires up
in program : myField.setValue = SomeValue; -> method doesn't fires up.
```

problem is with loop detection. If your logic is that you have 4 field and try to detect if any of those fields are changed and then fire method for change some values inside those fields :

```
@Override
protected void execChangedValue() throws ProcessingException {
  super.execChangedValue();
  valueFieldsChange(this);
}

protected void valueInPriceBoxFieldsChange(AbstractValueField field) {
    ... calculate some values in those fields....
}
```

and I get :

```
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.scout.rt.client.ui.form.fields.AbstractValueField.setValue(AbstractValueField.java:338) Loop detection in...
```

So I know the method `execChangedValue()` are not what I am looking for. Is there similar method with explained behavior ?

Marko

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let start to say that loop detection is useful in 90% of the cases.
The warning is displayed when you are inside an execChangedValue() and you try to update the value of the same field.

If I understand your example correctly you have inside your field:

```
public class FirstField extends AbstractStringField {

  @Override
  protected void execChangedValue() throws ProcessingException {
    calculateNewValues();
  }
}
```

And the method:

```
public void calculateNewValues() {
  //some logic to compute the new values: value1, value2, value3

  getFirstField().setValue(value1);
  getSecondField().setValue(value2);
  getThirdField().setValue(value3);
}
```

At this point, you really need to be sure that when the user sets the value in the `FirstField` to something, you might want to change it pragmatically to something else. This might be really confusing for the user.

---

If you are sure that you need to update the value, there is a way to set a value without triggering execChangedValue() on the field. I have proposed a new method: setValueWithoutChangedValueTrigger(T value) on the Eclipse Scout Form: [Controlling if execChangedValue() is called or not](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=754662&goto=1356939&#msg_1356939).

On the forum you will find a snippet that you can add to your field (or in a common template: `AbstractMyAppStringField`).

```
public class FirstField extends AbstractStringField {

  @Override
  protected void execChangedValue() throws ProcessingException {
    calculateNewValues();
  }

  public void setValueWithoutValueChangeTrigger(String value) {
    try {
      setValueChangeTriggerEnabled(false);
      setValue(value);
    }
    finally {
      setValueChangeTriggerEnabled(true);
    }
  }
}
```

And you will be able to use it:

```
public void calculateNewValues() {
  //some logic to compute the new values: value1, value2, value3

  getFirstField().setValueWithoutChangedValueTrigger(value1);
  getSecondField().setValueWithoutChangedValueTrigger(value2);
  getThirdField().setValueWithoutChangedValueTrigger(value3);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is great, but I would like to use this function whit FormData. If I set form data in scout server and import it in scout, I would like import use this function. Is this possible?