# Scout Eclipse linked fields

Tags: drop-down-menu, hierarchy, eclipse-scout

I have 4 smart field in scout linked together hierarhicly.

So let say I have Smart field A, B, C, D and A is parent of B, B is parent of C and C is parent of D. (logically, not necessary in scout sense.)

If I enter for example value in C field, A and B field must be auto filled in., but if I enter value in A field all other field need to be reset.

My problem is that if I have for A :

```
@Override
protected void execChangedValue() {

  B.resetValue();
  C.resetValue();
  D.resetValue();
}
```

and If I have in B :

```
@Override
protected void execChangedValue() {

  // get changed value
  final Long A_value = A.getValue();

  // reset call child fields
  C.resetValue();
  D.resetValue();

  if (A_value == null) {

    A.setValue(NewValueForA);
  }
}
```

This will create loop . B will set value in A, A will reset B,.... this is not what I want...

Is there a general approach in Scout to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For those complex cases, with the `setValueWithoutChangedValueTrigger(..)` I have introduced and explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28145391/91497). You can do:

```
getBField().setValueWithoutChangedValueTrigger(getBField().getInitValue());
getCField().setValueWithoutChangedValueTrigger(getCField().getInitValue());
getDField().setValueWithoutChangedValueTrigger(getDField().getInitValue());
```

and so on...

See also this related discussion: [Controlling if execChangedValue() is called or not](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=754662&goto=1356939&#msg_1356939).

Comment: Yes, I know for this solution, but I am wandering if there is a scout way to do it "right"... Thanks for answer.